# unexpected use of event when i pass another thing with it in parameter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Here is the event onClick thing that i have at one place .

```
<Button onClick={onClickAddTopics(e,dataid)}  variant="fab" mini color="primary" aria-label="Add" className={classes.button}>
                        <AddIcon />
 </Button>
```

and i am using that onClick evet handler at another place and here is the code .

```
addTopicEvent =(e,dataid)=>{
            e.stopPropagation();
            this.props.addEditTopicShow('add',{});
            this.chapterId=dataid;
            console.log('this.chapterId is',this.chapterId);

        }
```

but i am getting an error which says unexpected use of event .Is it wrong to pass events in parameter this way or is it wrong to pass events along with another paramter .I need the id of the clicked thing everytime .

Comment: You have two different names `onClickAddTopics ` and `addTopicEvent `. Which one is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event being used inside the function is not the object that `onClick` passes back. Also `onClick` expects a function and hence you should not call the function directly unless it returns back a function which onClick will execute.

The solution for your case can use curried function like

```
 addTopicEvent =(dataid)=>(e) => {
        e.stopPropagation();
        this.props.addEditTopicShow('add',{});
        this.chapterId=dataid;
        console.log('this.chapterId is',this.chapterId);

 }

 <Button onClick={addTopicEvent(dataid)}  variant="fab" mini color="primary" aria-label="Add" className={classes.button}>
                    <AddIcon />
 </Button>
```

or simply using arrow function like

```
 addTopicEvent =(e,dataid)=>{
        e.stopPropagation();
        this.props.addEditTopicShow('add',{});
        this.chapterId=dataid;
        console.log('this.chapterId is',this.chapterId);

 }

<Button onClick={(e) => addTopicEvent(e, dataid)}  variant="fab" mini color="primary" aria-label="Add" className={classes.button}>
        <AddIcon />
 </Button>
```

Comment: I am still getting the error  Line 82:  Unexpected use of 'event'  no-restricted-globals

Answer (score 1):

You sould pass event to function :

```
<Button onClick={(event)=>onClickAddTopics(event,dataid)}  variant="fab" mini color="primary" aria-label="Add" className={classes.button}>
                        <AddIcon />
 </Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

`onClick={onClickAddTopics(e,dataid)}` **calls** `onClickAddTopics` and uses its return value as the value of the `onClick`, exactly the way `x = bar()` **calls** `bar` and assigns its return value to `x`.

Pass in a function rather than *calling* a function (in this case, I'm using an arrow function):

```
<Button onClick={(e) => onClickAddTopics(e, dataid)} ...>
```